# Using Hash Maps and Searching Comma Delimited Files

Tags: perl, hashmap

Below is an example of searching comma delimited files using regex.  Does anyone know how to convert the below code into hash map searches.  If there is a match, the code should return the original lines from both files.

You don't have to use hash maps necessarily.  Your solution can include any other faster approach for searching arrays such as grep, hash, smart search, first, etc.

There are thousands of records in these documents.  The goal is to find the similar items in the 3rd column from file1.csv and 4th column in file2.csv.  if there is a match join the lines from both documents.

**Update**: Forgot to mention that it should print $line1 if it doesn't match anything in the @data2 array

```
   my $data_file1 = "file1.csv";  #contains in this file "james,smith,3 kids"
my $data_file2 = "file2.csv";  #contains in this file "jim,jones,tall,3 kids"

my $handle1;
my @temp_data1, @temp_data2;

open $handle1, '<', $data_file1;
chomp(@data1 = <$handle1>);
close $handle1;     

open  $handle1, '<', $data_file2;
chomp(@data2 = <$handle1>);
close $handle1; 

foreach my $line1 (@data1)
{   
    @temp_data1 = split /,/ , $line1;   
    $not_found =1;
    foreach my $line2 (@data2)
    {           
        @temp_data2 = split /,/ , $line2;   

        if($temp_data2[3] =~ /$temp_data1[2]$/)
        {
            $not_found =0;
            say $line1 .",". $line2;
        }
    }
    if($not_found)
    {
        say "$line1 was not found";
    }
}
```

Comment: *"You don't have to use hash maps necessarily"* Is this a school assignment?

Comment: The line `my @temp_data1, @temp_data2` declares `@temp_data1` as a lexical array variable, but the `my` doesn't apply to `@temp_data2` because it binds more tightly than the comma operator. You have written the equivalent of `my @temp_data1;` `@temp_data2;` and just mentioning an array in a statement on its own will be optimised out. `my` is of very little use without `use strict`, and you *must always* use it together with `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program you write. That simple measure would have alerted you to your error.

Comment: Initialising `$not_found = 1` is confusing. It would be much better to use `$found` and invert the logic, finishing with `say "$line1 was not found" unless $found`.

Comment: @Borodin No, this isn't a school assignment...lol.  I've been trying to come up with this solution for a while using perl, and i've declared those array as brevity.  Of course, you can't use them in that nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Populate a hash using the key field as the hash key and the row as the value. Then go through the other file, looking for matches in the hash.

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

@ARGV == 2
   or die("usage\n");

my ($data_file1, $data_file2) = @ARGV;

open(my $fh1, '<', $data_file1);
   or die("Can't open \"$data_file1\": $!\n");
open(my $fh2, '<', $data_file2);
   or die("Can't open \"$data_file2\": $!\n");

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ auto_diag => 2, binary => 1 });

my %data;
while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh2) ) {
   $data{ $row->[3] } = $row;
}

while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh1) ) {
   if ( my $linked_row = $data{ $row->[2] } ) {
      $csv->say(\*STDOUT, [ @$row, @$linked_row ]);
   } else {
      $csv->say(\*STDERR, $row);
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
script file1.csv file2.csv >merged.csv 2>unpaired.csv
```

- Assumes the 3rd column of the first file contains only unique values.
- Assumes the 4th column of the second file contains only unique values.

CPU: O(N+M) instead of O(N*M).
Mem: O(M) instead of O(N+M).
where N is the number of elements in the first file,
and M is the number of elements in the second file.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it should print $line1 if it doesn't match anything in the @data2 array

Comment: You'll need to load file 2 in the hash, then. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $data_file1 = "file1.csv";  #contains in this file "james,smith,3 kids"
my $data_file2 = "file2.csv";  #contains in this file "jim,jones,tall,3 kids"

my $handle1;

my %searchHash;

open $handle1, '<', $data_file1;
while (my $line = <$handle1>) {
    chomp($line);
    $searchHash{(split /,/,$line)[2]} = 0;
}
close $handle1;     

open  $handle1, '<', $data_file2;
while (my $line = <$handle1>) {
    chomp($line);
    my $key = (split /,/,$line)[3];
    $searchHash{$key}++ if(defined $searchHash{$key});
}
close $handle1;

foreach my $key (keys %searchHash) {
    print "$key ($searchHash{$key})\n";
}
```

Comment: Doesn't produce the request result (`james,smith,3 kids,jim,jones,tall,3 kids`).

Comment: What do you mean? It finds one match.

Comment: It needs to print `james,smith,3 kids,jim,jones,tall,3 kids`, not `3 kids`

Comment: My bad. Missed that part.